# what is a joint and a link, and how does the child and parent parameter work in the joint?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am working on modifying the PX4 gazebo simulator by adding a camera. I am unable to add the camera as the quadcopter take off but the camera get left behind. Can someone explain the difference and to connect them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15351/what-is-a-joint-and-a-link,-and-how-does-the-child-and-parent-parameter-work-in-the-joint?/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2792/vinh-k/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please read these tutorials:

- [Build a robot](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_robot)

  - [Attach a sensor to a robot](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=add_laser&cat=build_robot)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2792/vinh-k/) on 2017-01-31**:
I think I understand the difference now. What is does this part mean?opencv::link. In addition, iris::base_link